# Checking for a Microsoft graph token expiration

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using access and refresh token to do some Microsoft graph queries. When the access token expires, I do the standard token refresh procedure using the refresh token. When I make a query using an expired token, I get the following error:

```
{ 
"error": {
      "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
      "message": "CompactToken validation failed with reason code: 80049228.", 
      "innerError": { 
          "request-id": "f4853bd8-1cf1-44eb-b4a6-b3c695223762", 
          "date": "2019-09-05T17:39:42" 
        }
    }
}
```

I've wrapped a query in a try/catch, and when I get an error I'm comparing the message, as InvalidAuthenticationToken can be found in more cases than just expiration. Is there a better way to check for access token expiration? Is there a reason the error code number itself isn't exposed?

Comment: I should add that this is OBO token I'm using on the server side. Put otherwise, the client has given their token and I've exchanged it for an access and refresh token, which is what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use the [MSAL SDK](https://aka.ms/aaddev) and let it handle the cache/refresh of tokens.

Alternatively, I would recommend simply trying to acquire a token, and upon failure ([typically AADSTS700020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes)) initiate a user action to re-acquire a token.

The reasoning is that tokens can become invalid due to circumstances beyond your control (certificate revocation, conditional access policy, multi-factor requirement). Simply checking the token expiration does not guarantee a successful result if you use the token.

Comment: This is a server making a request with an OBO token, so having a user refresh their token isn't an option.

Comment: That's just it -- you need to design an option for a user to re-authenticate to your app so that you can refresh the user assertion that you use in the OBO request.

If user interaction is completely not an option, then you will likely need to go the app-only route.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred due to expiration of access token. You can access the API just using access token

The default lifetime of an access token is variable. When issued, the Microsoft identity platform assigns a random value ranging between **60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average)** as the default lifetime of an access token.
while access token is expired you can get new access token by this Microsoft API

```
data = {
   "grant_type": "refresh_token",
   "client_id": "Your Client_id",
   "client_secret": "Your Client_secret",
   "refresh_token": refresh_token
}
response = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token', data)
```

when the new access token and refresh token generated using above request you can access further Microsoft graph queries